# Columns constraints in Spark tables

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am creating a table from CSV file in apache SPARK. Is it possible to create a table with not null constraint or primary key-foreign key constraints?

Comment: Could add some context? Why do you need this? And what would be the expected behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to define constraints on Spark tables / `DataFrames`. While `StructFields` can be defined as nullbale or not this property is not enforced on runtime. There are multiple reasons why constraints like this wouldn't be useful in practice but the fundamental one is that Spark SQL is not a database. In general it doesn't have any control over the data sources and validates data only on read so the only possible approach would be to fail on access.